# For loop not finding value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I'm having some issues with the code below. I want to find the number "1" on a sheet and return the location as a set of variables. The code finishes the loop before finding the number and I can't figure out why. Could the formatting(ie, merged cell) on the source document flub it some how? I'm new to vba and would really appreciate and help or insight or recommended reading.

```
   Dim arr(0 To 100, 0 To 100) As Variant     
       Dim d As Long, c As Long
            For d = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                If arr(d, c) = "1" Then
                    Exit For
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c
            Next d
```

This code was admittedly taken from Tim Williams and altered for my use.

Comment: Try without the quotes around the one. ie `If arr(d, c) = 1` instead of `If arr(d, c) = "1"`.

Comment: Just taking another look, I'm not sure what your aiming for here as your code doesn't do anything, unless you haven't given the whole code. At the moment you don't do anything if `arr =1` because your trying to check if `arr(d,c)` = 1 but you haven't populated arr with any values. Unless you meant to replace `arr(d,c)` with `Sheet.Cells(d,c)` or something. Just another note you can't double the `Exit For` up. You would need something like a boolean you can set to true to exit the second loop.

Comment: Maybe we could benefit from the original Tim Williams code.

Comment: No idea where that might be from...

Comment: Where do you set `arr`?

Comment: Your code is in no way connected to the spreadsheet data (as others have pointed out). The code creates in some sense an empty spreadsheet (the array), and searches that. That's why it is not returning any result, because it is searching "emptiness".

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, I'm learning a lot. @Simon this is only a snippet of my code(lots of errors, one step at a time), but both d and c run to 101 when debugging. After the for loops, the integers are used for a location to copy from. `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(d, c + 2), Cells(d + 14, c + 2)).Copy`  The original code was written as a Function that allowed a boolean before double `Exit For`. I'll have to rethink that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well unless you give us the whole code or more information there isn't much help someone can give you. What you have given us does nothing as you will never find a 1 during your loops because `arr` doesn't contain anything (as said above).